# Magento 2.3 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mime_content_type()

Tags: blocks, admin-panel, magento2.3, fatal-error, php-7.2

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mime_content_type()** in  when trying to upload image from admin blocks.
Please check screenshot
[image]

Comment: Do you have any custom module ? Which might be conflicting with app/code/Magento/Cms/etc/di.xml

Comment: no there is "no" custom module which is conflicting app/code/Magento/Cms/etc/di.xml

Comment: You will need to enable php fileinfo extension.

Comment: ok i will check and let you know

Comment: enabling fileinfo extension helped me Thanks.

Comment: @DhavalSolanki Do you find a solution?

Comment: @DavidDuong I think according to Dhaval Solanki,he is enable fileinfo extension and problem gone

Comment: @sumeetbajaj Thank you!!!

Comment: @DavidDuong Yes, I have enabled  fileinfo extension and it worked :)

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to elaborate for those that are want to know if they have fileinfo enabled and how to enable.

The below is for Centos will be similar for other Linux flavors

- `php -m | grep fileinfo` (if you do not see any results you do not have it enabled)
- `php-config --extension-dir`  this will show you the location for you extensions, check if fileinfo.so is there
- If you have fileinfo extension just uncomment for you php.ini (can be found with `php -i | grep php.ini`)
- If you need to get the so file do the next few steps
- `php -v` to get your php version
- Go to https://www.php.net/downloads and download to your server the correct version
- `which phpize` to get full path to phpize and take note of it
- `tar -zxvf php-x.x.x.tar.gz`
- `cd php-x.x.x/ext/fileinfo/`
- `./configure -with-php-config=/use-path-from-above( without the phpize )/php-config`
- `make && make install` when this completes you should be done
- `php -m | grep fileinfo` to confirm that it installed correctly
- Enable fileinfo extension from php.ini 
  `extension=fileinfo.so`
- Restart php-fpm `service php-fpm restart`

Comment: I'm on cPanel so was the case of using easyapache wysiwyg to add fileinfo php extensions for the different versions of php but this answer pinpointed exactly what I was missing. More importantly this is not listed as a required extension https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html#required-php-extensions