# Magento 2.3.3 - Error while uploading image to products in admin - A technical problem with the server created an error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, adminhtml

I am facing this error.

I have tried various things like changing fileUploader to ImageUploader, flush, clean cache etc..

But nothing so far is working.

I further checked the `Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\Content\Files getCount` function and it is returning `0` count. Checked and no modules overriding this file.

Permissions is `777`. n the admin even images are not showing however the image do exist in folders.

Checked logs and they are not updating when I am trying to upload the file. The file is uploading but not shown on admin.

`cms/wysiwyg_images/contents/?form_key=dsfdf&node=sdfdsfs--&isAjax=true` -- it is throwing 500 Error

`Magento version 2.3.3`

Comment: I'm aware of this issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186909/magento2-wysiwyg-images-show-broken-thumbnail although you are using a much newer version. Sounds similar to what you've described.

Comment: I checked and found by error reporting on that it was a code issue(Magento core) and https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/258427/magento-2-3-fatal-error-uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-function-mime-content